# Homotopy equivalence between topological mapping cone and the algebraic mapping cone

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

In the Wikipedia article of [mapping cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_cone_(homological_algebra)) there’s the following:

> This complex is called the cone in analogy to the mapping cone (topology) of a continuous map of topological spaces $\phi \colon X \rightarrow Y$: **the complex of singular chains of the topological cone $\mathrm{cone}(\phi)$ is homotopy equivalent to the cone (in the chain-complex-sense) of the induced map of singular chains of $X$ to $Y$.**

I would like to see an explicit homotopy equivalence. We clearly have a chain map from $C_{n-1}(X) \oplus C_n(Y)$ to $C_n(\mathrm{cone}(\phi))$ (for an element $\sigma \in C_{n-1}(X)$ triangulate the cone $\sigma * \{1\}$; for an element in $C_n(Y)$ just map it to the base of the mapping cone). I couldn’t think of maps going in the other direction. Could someone help?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think a map $|\Delta^n|\to C_\phi$ need induce maps $|\Delta^n|\to Y$ or $|\Delta^{n-1}|\to X$ in any direct way, there's probably some 'swindle'.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{Sing}\DeclareMathOperator{\Cone}{Cone}$
*Added later*. Probably the correct thing is to say that $C_\varphi$ is a homotopy pushout (the other map being the trivial map from $X$ to a point) in spaces while $\Cone(f)$ is a homotopy pushout in chain complexes, and that $\C$ preserves homotopy pushouts up to homotopy. I thought this was true but reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501885/decoupling-the-algebra-from-the-topology-in-cellular-homology) post leaves me doubting.